# LINQ Select 2 columns, add string, and add to list

Tags: c#, linq

I need to submit a list of complete addresses to BingMaps for directions. My table has separate columns for Address and Zip Code.

Example Address: 1 State Street New York NY
Example Zip Code: 10001

I need each entry of the list to have a space or comma. How can I achieve this with Linq?

One variation I was trying:

```
var iFou = _context.PostFous
    .Where(m => m.FouZero == zero && m.FouAddr != null)
    .Select(p => new { p.FouAddr, " ", p.FouPost })
    .ToList();
```

SOLUTION:

```
List<string> iFou = _context.PostFous
                .Where(m => m.FouZero == zero && m.FouAddr != null)
                .Select(p => $"{p.FouAddr} {" "} {p.FouPost}")
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you select an anonymous type if you just need a single string.

```
List<string> addressList = _context.PostFous
    .Where(m => m.FouZero == zero && m.FouAddr != null)
    .Select(p => $"{p.FouAddr} {p.FouPost}")
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. `string.Join()` will concatenate your array of strings, with your choice of separator in between. More on this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join

```cs
var iFou = _context.PostFous
    .Where(m => m.FouZero == zero && m.FouAddr != null)
    .Select(p => string.Join(' ', new [] {p.FouAddr, p.FouPost /* etc */})
    .ToList();
```